# How do the variables in .twig files work?

Tags: theming

I am using a theme based off awesome zymphonies theme.

I'm trying to use the site_logo variable from page.html.twig, but it doesn't have access to it, instead I have to use the page.header region, which somehow (I need clarification as to how) calls upon the code in block--system-branding-block.html.twig and there I can use site_logo.

So my question is why site_logo can only be accessed from that twig, and what would I need to do in order to use site_logo, or any other variable in any other twig file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `site_logo` block is available in the `page.header` region because that logo block itself is placed into that region using Drupal's block layout: mydrupalsite.com/admin/structure/block

Drupal's template/twig system is a set in parent and children type templates. So the `page.header` region/template may print `{{ site_logo }}` - but the contents of `{{ site_logo }}` are outputted in `block--system-branding-block.html.twig`

Blocks are placed in regions so you can't really access a block directly in `page.html.twig` unless you add it programmatically.

Probably what you are looking to do is place the `site_logo` block into the region which approximates the position you want it to be displayed. Then if you want to "fine tune" it you can override that regions template using the following naming convention:

```
my_drupal_theme/templates/region--[region].html.twig
```

E.g.

```
my_drupal_theme/templates/region--header.html.twig
```

Then maybe your `region--header.html.twig` file looks like:

```
<div class="my-custom-wrapper-class">
  {{ site_logo }}
</div>
```

What can be really helpful here is knowing the basics of twig template naming conventions - and also turning on "twig template debugging" which gives you template names you can use to override.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/twig-template-naming-conventions
https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates#s-enable-debugging

Just for completeness: if you did want to load the logo directly in your `page.html.twig` you could add it via a `hook_preprocess_HOOK`

```
@file my_drupal_theme/my_drupal_theme.theme

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function my_drupal_theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $block_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
  $plugin_block = $block_manager->createInstance('system_branding_block', []);
  $variables['site_logo'] = $plugin_block->build();
}
```